# How to create a listbox type child control which hold both text item and text with checkbox item using microsoft MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

[image: Listbox control]

How to create a control in mfc which takes both checkbox and text in one column.

Comment: [How to Create an Owner-Drawn List Box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298352.aspx). This is a Windows API implementation, that can easily be translated to MFC.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for the suggestions yes indeed it's little difficult to do but it's doable. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `CMFCPropertyGridControl`.

I'd also risk a look at the `CMFCTasksPane` control.